# How to return data from stored procedure in a view SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

So i have this code:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(period)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT period FROM atbv_Accounting_OrdersDeliveries WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL) AS Periods

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    N'SELECT  ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM (SELECT
    ArticleID, period, SUM(Amount) As Total
    FROM atbv_Accounting_OrdersDeliveries 
    WHERE InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY ArticleID, period
    ) AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(TOTAL) 
          FOR period IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
 EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

I saved in i a stored procedure as i cannot declare variables in a view. Is there a way to call this procedure in a view? Note that column amount is dynamic as well :)

Thanks!

Comment: You say SQL Server 2017, but tag SQL Server 2008 R2. How come?

Comment: My bad. Edit done.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to execute a stored procedure from a view. Also, there is no way to execute a user defined function that contains dynamic SQL.

Comment: So there is no way i can used the returned info?

Comment: I'd advise anybody who is unsure to read http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html and http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html, then you will know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Stored Procedure instead of a view.

If that isn't possible for any reason, you can create a SQL Server Agent Job that periodically fills a table using a stored procedure and the client than uses the "cached" data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a dynamic view, what would be the point?

If you want to know how to share data from stored procedures then

> [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html)

is a great text. If you want to understand dynamic SQL then I recommend

> [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

by the same author, [Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/about_me.html). Both topics are too expansive for a simple answer on Stack Overflow.